# Make JSF Tomahawk tree2 node selectable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

Is it possible to make `<t:tree2>` tree node selectable? I would need to select a node, and based on this selection to print out certain info on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Myfaces Wiki - Tree2](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Tree2) says

> "Almost any type of JSF component (text, image, checkbox, etc.) can be rendered inside the nodes"

So I guess you you can place a button for example and use it for interacting and showing the needed data

I haven't worked with Tomahawk nor its tree2... but I think whatever i suggested would work for any tree... Also.. i'm not so sure that Tomahawk is the library to be used for fancy web app... You should check primefaces component library its for JSF 2 and its showcase is amazingly BIG and RICH... take a look at their tree , it got all you ever wanted and event more

[PRIMEFACES Tree - Single Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeSelectionSingle.jsf)

[PRIMEFACES Tree](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeHome.jsf)

Comment: Thanks. I ment selectable in a way that I would click on it and it would be highlighted and selected. I still don't see how this could be done using text, image, etc...?

Comment: if you take for example a checkbox ... and click on it, it will be selected... if you wrap it with div and on change of selection change the background of the div , it gets highlighted ... am i in the wrong direction , of course a little bit of jquery magic will do the fancy trick...

Comment: so there isn't a simple, normal solution? there has to be some "magic"...?

Comment: Ok. I was affraid of that answer - "use better library", it might be too late now. :-(

Comment: I'm not saying tomahawk isn't good enougth, never worked with it... but if it takes to much time and effort to achieve your goal, you should reconsider your choosen framework